# AIMS style reference

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

This [journal](http://aimsciences.org/journal/1078-0947/DCDS-A_Tex) requires AIMS style references. It has a sample whose hyperlink is on the name of the cited paper:

```
\bibitem{rB} (MR1301779) [10.1007/978-1-4612-0873-0]
\newblock J.  Smoller,
\newblock \emph{Shock Waves and Reaction-Diffusion Equations},
\newblock 2$^{nd}$ edition,  Springer-Verlag, New York, 1994.
```

[image]

I tried to mimic the reference style in my code:

```
\bibitem{SH}(MR715321) [10.1017/S0004972700025946]
\newblock D.~J. Scott and R.~M. Huggins,
\newblock On the embedding of processes in {B}rownian motion and the law of the iterated logarithm for reverse martingales,
\newblock \emph{Bull. Austral. Math. Soc.}, \textbf{27} (1983), 443--459.
```

However, the blue hyperlink for this cited paper is on the name of the journal:

[image]

Is there something wrong in my code? Can you help me out of this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the buggy `aims.cls` (which even advertises itself incorrectly as providing class `dcds.cls` instead of `aims.cls`…).

There is also an inconsistency in the formatting between [`Template_1.pdf`](http://aimsciences.org/journals/tex-sample/Template_1.pdf) and their [instructions for authors](http://aimsciences.org/journals/tex-sample/Instructions4authors.pdf). The latter has the link on the title for articles, and the former has it on the journal title.

The theory is that you supply your `\bibitem` with an MR number and a DOI. And if there is a DOI, it gets automatically linked to the title. Except they've done this by abusing the `\emph` macro to insert the DOI hyperlink.

This works OK with books when the title should be emphasised but fails for articles when the title is upright and the journal name is emphasised.

Assuming the instructions for authors is correct rather than `Template_1.tex`, you can fool their class code by using `\textit{…}` for the journal name and `\emph{\upshape …}` for the article title.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{aims}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\begin{document}
\cite{SH}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{SH}(MR715321) [10.1017/S0004972700025946]
\newblock D.~J. Scott and R.~M. Huggins,
\newblock \emph{\upshape On the embedding of processes in {B}rownian motion and the law of the iterated logarithm for reverse martingales},
\newblock \textit{Bull. Austral. Math. Soc.}, \textbf{27} (1983), 443--459.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!